# tibco bw 6.4 XSLT out of sync with schema component properties

Tags: xslt, tibco, tibco-business-works

During mapping to subprocesses, Tibco duplicates the xsd structure and I often get an `xslt out of sync` error.
Is this a Tibco related issue? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the xsd schema changes (input of the subprocess). An element becomes facutative for example (minoccurs = 0). It is therefore necessary to update the transformation xslt to align it with the schema. To do this, just right click on the mapping and check the correction of the error